# Connecting to docker address from Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I'm using Windows 10 Home, so I installed "Docker Toolbox on Windows" to learn some Docker.

After successfull I went through "Part 2" of Docker's official Guide:

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

As a result I generated Image friendlyhello and ran it:

```
$ docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production 
deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I'm now opening my browser Chrome and trying to get into:
0.0.0.0:4000 or 0.0.0.0:80 I'm getting:
"This site can’t be reached". So how to correctly use it while using "Docker Toolbow for Windows"? On linux there was no problem, just run and open in chrome 0.0.0.0:4000.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a solution by myself :)

Had to write docker-machine ip, to get ip I have to connect to.